# How to update gitlab ee ( gitlab-ee 9.4.0) to latest one in linux?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, updates

I need to update gitlab-ee 9.4.0 to latest one in **linux** .
Which exact command should i use to update it :
Can anyone please suggest here.

1. To take Backup of current gitlab
2. To update gitlab-ee 9.4.0 to latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation on how to update GitLab here: https://about.gitlab.com/update/

Comment: Thanks Emily. But do you know if i update to latest version whether shall i get compatibility issue ?  because i have lot of projects, repos present in gitlab .